# WebMatrix - CS0103: O nome 'ViewBag' não existe no contexto atual

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Boa tarde!

Estou implementando uma aplicação em Web Matrix. Minha página é em .cshtml (c# com html). Eu quero usar a Classe ViewBag, porém não a localizo nem em `@using System.Web.Mvc;` nem em outro lugar. Procurei pela internet mas não entendi bem o procedimento. Baixei a dll Unity.mvc3 mas também não resolveu.

Meu arquivo .cshtml está assim:

```
@using System;
@using System.Collections;
@using System.Collections.Generic;
@using System.ComponentModel;
@using System.Linq;
@using System.Text;
@using System.Web;
@using Newtonsoft.Json;

@{

    ArrayList header = new ArrayList { "Task Name", "Hours"};
    ArrayList data1 = new ArrayList {"Work", 2};
    ArrayList data2 = new ArrayList { "Eat", 2 };
    ArrayList data3 = new ArrayList { "Sleep", 2 };
    ArrayList data = new ArrayList {header, data1, data2, data3};

    string dataStr = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.None);

    ViewBag.Data = new HtmlString(dataStr);
}

<script>
    var data = JSON.parse('@ViewBag.Data');
    console.log(data);
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<style>
    table {
        border: 1px #c0c0c0 solid;
        width: 100%;
    }
    table th {
        background-color: #00f;
        color: #fff;
    }
    table td {
        background-color: #f0f0f0;
        color: #0c0c0c;
    }
</style>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Teste</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Nas pesquisas pela internet ouvi falar que deveria fazer alguma configuração no `views/web.config`, o meu está vazio. Tentei colocar a parametrização dos exemplos na internet, mas a Classe ViewBag também não foi reconhecida. Abaixo o meu `views/web.config`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está também a pasta de dll:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aqui está também o `Web.config`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por acaso devo instalar o mvc3 ou alguma dll? Agradeço desde já pela ajuda.

Comment: Esse jeito de usar `ViewBag` está péssimo. Qual a versão do ASP.NET MVC?

Comment: A minha versão é 4.0_3.0.0.0. Me apresentaram esta ferramenta (o WebMatrix) e conheci por meio dela o cshtml. Ainda estou aprendendo a lidar com ela. Na verdade o `ViewBag` nem está sendo reconhecido, este está sendo tratado como texto.

Comment: Será que devo substituir esta versão do MVC no diretório? `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35`

Comment: Não acho uma boa ideia. No seu lugar, eu [faria a instalação do MVC4 usando um instalador](http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4).

Comment: Obrigado Cigano! Farei o que você me recomendou! Depois digo o que aconteceu.

Comment: Mesmo instalando o MVC4 no endereço `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35` o ViewBag continua desconhecido.

Comment: Pergunta: onde exatamente fica esta hospedagem? Aparentemente fica na Azure, certo?

Comment: Ele está na minha máquina localmente, e eu estou usando o IIS Express como servidor.

Comment: Há alguma necessidade específica para o uso do MVC4? Ele já está bem defasado da versão estável hoje, que é o MVC5. Nem sei se vale a pena configurar o MVC4.

Comment: É porque quero que o ´ViewBag´ seja conhecido na página ´.cshtml´. Lá no arquivo ele estava sendo visto como uma variável e não como um objeto.

Comment: A minha pergunta é outra. Você não poderia usar o MVC5 ao invés do MVC4?

Comment: Posso sim, sem problemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vou te passar um exemplo de `Views/Web.config` do ASP.NET MVC5 (estou procurando um bom exemplo de MVC4 mas está difícil, e por isso perguntei se era possível a troca da versão do *framework*):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler" />
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>

  <system.web>
    <compilation>
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Com isso, `@ViewBag` deve ser reconhecido em *View*.

---

Instalei um Visual Studio 2012 aqui pra gerar um `Views/Web.config` pra você no MVC4:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
    <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

    <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
    <pages
        validateRequest="false"
        pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"
        userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <controls>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo suporte, Cigano! Vou fazer os procedimentos que você me passou e depois digo o que aconteceu!